# Isomorphism between $S(\mathfrak{n})^N$ and $Z(U(\mathfrak{n}))$

Tags: reference-request, lie-algebras

Let $\mathfrak{g}$ is a simple Lie algebra, $\mathfrak{b}$ - borel subalgebra, $\mathfrak{n}$ - maximal nilpotent subalgebra of $\mathfrak{b}$, $N=exp(\mathfrak{n})$, $U(\mathfrak{n})$ - universal enveloping algebra of $\mathfrak{n}$, $S(\mathfrak{n})$ - symmetric algebra, $N$ acts on $\mathfrak{n}^*$ (dual space) by coadjoint action, thus $N$ acts on $S(\mathfrak{n})$, $S(\mathfrak{n})^N$ is the invatiants of this action. Where prooved that $S(\mathfrak{n})^N$ is isomorphic $Z(U(\mathfrak{n}))$ (center) by simmetrization map? Beforehand thanks for help.